Is there a way to IGNORE INDEX (PRIMARY) or FORCE INDEX in hql?
I have the below hql query:
@Query("SELECT es FROM EmailSubscription es "
    + "JOIN FETCH es.subscriber s "
    + "WHERE es.subscriptionTypeId = :typeId "
    + "AND es.active = :active "
    + "AND es.id > :batchStartId "
    + "ORDER BY es.id ASC")
@QueryHints(@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.fetchSize", value = "1000"))

Unfortunately it takes about 2+ seconds to fetch 1k records loading EmailSubscription and its relation subscriber.
This native sql query finishes under 500 ms, but since it is native sql it doesn't load its relation (subscriber).
@Query(value = "SELECT es.* FROM subscriptions.email_subscriptions es "
    + "IGNORE INDEX (PRIMARY) "
    + "JOIN subscriptions.subscribers s ON es.subscriber_id = s.id "
    + "WHERE es.type_id = :typeId "
    + "AND es.active = :active "
    + "AND es.id > :batchStartId "
    + "ORDER BY es.id ", nativeQuery = true) 

Is there a way I can force an index or choose to ignore primary index in my hql query?

Unless I am mistaken you are comparing the performance of two different database workloads. The hibernate query is running the Join Fetch to retrieve the related subscriber details which will likely be running an additional SQL query for each individual subscriber of each emailsubscription.
So you are looking at something like N * M in terms of the number of queries being submitted to the database. Where N is the number of emailsubscriptions and M is the number of subscribers per emailsubscription. In comparison the native query is submitting a single request to the database.
if you configure a batch size for the subscriber fetches you could reduce this to something like N * M/BatchSize
hibernate batch fetching

In my case there is just 1 Subscriber per Subscription. Also I am doing 'JOIN FETCH es.subscriber s' , which afaik will join tables and bring data for both entities in same go. Please correct me if my understanding is incorrect.

that isn't how I understand that it works but I could be wrong. If you have 1 emailsubscription with 1 subscriber I expect it would be running 2 SQL queries on the database. You can check this by monitoring the query log/query store on whichever RDBMS you are using to see what queries it is executing.

In JPQL you can't use IGNORE INDEX. However, I doubt that the difference in query execution time is due to IGNORE INDEX. Your queries are different.

In case of JPQL you do LEFT OUTER JOIN.
In case of SQL you do INNER JOIN.

With left outer join you get all subscriptions. With inner join you get only those subscriptions that have subscribers, which can be much less.
